# How to filter by attributes in layered navigation Magento?

Tags: magento

I have two attributes in my Admin: Color and Size.

This attributes haves this configuration:

Scope: global
Catalog input type: Drop down
Apply To: all 
Use in layered navigation: Filterable with results

And I have configurable products that haves simple products. For example:

CONFIGURABLE: MY T-SHIRT 
SIMPLE 1: MY T-SHIRT with Color = White and Size = L
SIMPLE 2: MY T-SHIRT with Color = Black and Size = L

CONFIGURABLE: MY OTHER T-SHIRT 
SIMPLE 1: MY OTHER T-SHIRT with Color = White and Size = S
SIMPLE 2: MY OTHER T-SHIRT with Color = Black and Size = M

But I cant't see filter by "Color" or "Size" in layered navigation. I just can filter by price and subcategories.

Why are those attributes not appearing in my layered navigation?

Answer (score 6):

Could possibly be one of these causing the problem:

1. The category is not set to be anchored.  Go to the category in the admin area and go to the  'Display Settings' tab.  Make sure that the 'Is Anchor' option is set to yes.
2. The attributes are not in the correct attribute set for the products in the category you are viewing
3. The products in the category do not have values for those attributes

Comment: #3 is what was catching me out